# DependencyProperty callback not called

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I'm currently doing an usercontrol with C#/WPF and i'm using some DependencyProperty objects.

What I want to do is when the value changes, we call a callback method to process some data... I saw that there is a PropertyChangedCallback class for this purpose, but it doesn't work..

Here's my code:

UserControl:

```
public partial class TimeLine : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FramecountProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FrameCount", typeof(Int32), typeof(TimeLine), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(FrameCountChanged)));

    public Int32 FrameCount
    {
        get { return (Int32)this.GetValue(FramecountProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(FramecountProperty, value); }
    }

    // More code...

    public static void FrameCountChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<!-- Time line container -->
<controls:TimeLine Grid.Row="2" Header="Storyboard" FrameCount="{Binding FrameCount}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
private Int32 frameCount;
public Int32 FrameCount
{
    get { return this.frameCount; }
    // this is from: https://github.com/ShyroFR/CSharp-Elegant-MVVM
    set { this.NotifyPropertyChanged(ref this.frameCount, value); }
}

public MainViewModel()
{
    this.FrameCount = 42;
}
```

I'm I doing it the wrong way?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try this FrameCount="{Binding FrameCount, Mode=TwoWay}" i dont think it binds two ways, you have to tell it to do it, you can also add it to your dependency property if you want it to bind two ways by default

Comment: Show how you have implemented `NotifyPropertyChanged`. And don't worry about two-way binding. You don't have one here, and you don't need one. The PropertyChangedCallback should be called when the source property changes (i.e. also for one-way bindings).

Comment: Also make sure that the binding has a source object. i.e. that you have set a DataContext somewhere (to an instance of class MainViewModel). Is the TimeLine control showing anything at all?

Comment: I implemented the NotifyPropertyChanged like this: https://github.com/ShyroFR/CSharp-Elegant-MVVM/blob/master/CSharp-Elegant-MVVM/CSharp-Elegant-MVVM/MVVM_Framework/ViewModelBase.cs (i'm using this class)
I tried to do the `Mode=TwoWay` and it's not working...
I've also put a break point in the callback method and I can't reach it in debug mode.

Comment: Ok, and did you set the DataContext anywhere?

Comment: I've set the DataContext on my MainWindow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution, by finding the ancestor.

```
<controls:TimeLine Grid.Row="2" Header="Storyboard" FrameCount="{Binding Path=DataContext.FrameCount, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please explain the reason behind this?

Comment: The reason @SafiMustafa is that the `TimeLine` control is inheriting its `DataContext` from its parent control, which doesn't contain a `FrameCount` property so it can't find it. The fancy relative source syntax tells the control where to look for the `FrameCount` property, in this case, the `DataContext` of the first `Window` control it finds going upwards in the chain.

Comment: I was struggling like half of the day yesterday. You saved my today! :) :) Thank YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Add `Mode=TwoWay` to your binding. By default binding for custom dependency properties are OneWay.

Comment: Sure, but the PropertyChangedCallback is called whenever the dependency property changes its value, especially also when the source is a one-way binding.

Comment: True, but value changes on the UI are not reported back to the dependency property. Default behavior of customs controls is the have read-only binding unless explicitly set to TwoWay.

Comment: You probably mean "reported back to the source property". But that doesn't matter here. OP has a source property that changes, but the target dependency property isn't set (I'm pretty sure because no DataContext is set). No two-way binding involved. There is no indication in the question that the control ever wants to change the source property (in which case two-way would be necessary).