# WPF sending value to reusable usercontrol

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I think this is a beginner's question for intermediate stuff in WFP. 
I have a user control which acts as a radiobutton using two normal buttons:
(buttons changes color to show the current choice)

```
<UserControl x:Class="UI.UserControls.RadioUC" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
<Stackpanel DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>

    <Button x:Name="BtnYes" Content="YES" Click="BtnYes_Click">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Command}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>

        <Button x:Name="BtnNo" Content="NO" Click="BtnNo_Click">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Command}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
</Stackpanel>
</UserControl>
```

And the codebehind consists of 2 dependency properties Title & IsYes.
When the buttons are clicked using the click events, IsYes property is modified.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(RadioUC),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsYesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsYes", typeof(bool), typeof(RadioUC),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(bool), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

public bool IsYes {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsYesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsYesProperty, value); }
    }

public String Title {
        get { return (String)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

private void BtnYes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsYes = true;
        //BtnYes.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.ForestGreen);
        //BtnNo.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
    }

private void BtnNo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsYes = false;
        //BtnNo.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.ForestGreen);
        //BtnYes.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
    }
```

And finally this how I use it:

```
<uc:RadioUC Title="Is it YES" IsYes="{Binding IsLocalYes, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

When the buttons are clicked individually, the IsYes property of the usercontrol gets modified successfully. There is no problem. The problem is when I modified IsLocalYes programmatically in the hosting window of the usercontrol, this change does not propagate into the usercontrol. So the question is how can I modify IsYes property of the usercontrol when IsLocalYes property changes?

Comment: What and where is IsLocalYes?

Comment: Have you tried to change the `ControlTemplate` of `RadioButton` instead of creating a `UserControl`? See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview

Comment: @Andy, IsLocalYes is a property of the host window's viewmodel where there are many reusable usercontrols.

Comment: Three things: First, is the binding actually resolved successfully? In other words, is the DataContext used by the `uc:RadioUC` actually the viewmodel containing the `IsLocalYes` property? We can't tell because we cannot see... Second, what does the implementation of the `IsLocalYes` property look like? Third, your dependency property needs to implement a callbakc that manipulates the user control whenever its value changes from the "outside".

Comment: @elgonzo, I cannot figure out how to implement a callback. The first two point are okay. I will edit the question right away. Can you tell me how to put a callback in the usercontrol?

Comment: See for example the code in this question (random pick) for how to implement a callback for when the value of a DP changes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997544/dependencyproperty-callback-not-called

Comment: @elgonzo, I actually continued with the ToggleButton but afterwards I successfully used the callbacks too, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating your own `UserControl`, for what you want to achieve it's better to use a `ToggleButton` and change the `ControlTemplate`/`Style`.

Read also this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview)

---

**Solution:**

ToggleButton-Style:

```
<Style x:Key="YesNoToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_GRIDYES" Background="Gray" MinWidth="6" MinHeight="6">
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">YES</TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_GRIDNO" Background="Gray" MinWidth="6" MinHeight="6">
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">NO</TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_GRIDYES" Property="Background" Value="ForestGreen"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_GRIDNO" Property="Background" Value="ForestGreen"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Use it like this:

```
<ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource YesNoToggleButtonStyle}" IsChecked="{Binding IsLocalYes, Mode=TwoWay}">Is it YES</ToggleButton>
```